# Dynamic Object with Dollar on String

Tags: c#, winforms

Im usíng this code to get views of video from youtube:

```
WebClient ccn = new WebClient();

string dog = ccn.DownloadString("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/5WEK6HgXBsQ?v=2&alt=json");

dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dog);

foreach (string view in obj.entry.media$group.yt$statistics.viewCount)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(view);
}
```

But on string `foreach (string view in obj.entry.media$group.yt$statistics.viewCount)` VS 2013 return error on the `$`-sign.

Partial of Youtube json is:

```
"yt$statistics":{
         "favoriteCount":"0",
         "viewCount":"730"
      },
```

How would you use this with $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `JObject`

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(dog); //(OR JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dog) as JObject;)

foreach (string view in obj["entry"]["media$group"]["yt$statistics"]["viewCount"])
{

}
```

Comment: @Federal09 but don't forget. your object hierarchy is not correct. Try to use some tool like [jsonview](http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Delete ["media$group"] and it work i have see now =)

Answer (score 0):

Using .NET 6 it can be solved like this with `dynamic` or built in `JsonObject`:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

const string Json = "{\"yt$statistics\":{\"favoriteCount\":\"0\",\"viewCount\":\"730\"}}";

JsonObject obj = JsonNode.Parse(Json).AsObject();
string viewCount = (string)obj["yt$statistics"]["viewCount"];

dynamic dynobj = JsonNode.Parse(Json);
string viewCountDyn = (string)dynobj["yt$statistics"]["viewCount"];
```