# deserialize json in C# with illegal variable characters

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm writing a .NET library (using Newtonsoft) that interacts with a REST service, and I have a service that's returning json, but the json id field is called '$id'. So I can't just create a corresponding $id property in my C# data class. I tried to use something like

```
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
    public class DocData
    {
        [JsonProperty("$id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

but while Name gets assigned, the id property does not. Anyone know how to map this json key to .NET?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Object with Dollar on String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318261/dynamic-object-with-dollar-on-string)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a bug in JSON.NET, and I think you should [report it](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic). It works fine in LINQPad for any property name except `$id`.

```
void Main()
{
    var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new DocData{id = "hi", Name = "world"}).Dump();
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocData>(s).Dump();
}

public class DocData
{
    // [JsonProperty("i$d")] // this would work 
    // [JsonProperty("_id")] // as would this
    // [JsonProperty("$name")] // and even this
    [JsonProperty("$id")] // but this fails
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Evidently Json.NET uses `$id` as a reserved word to help it deal with object references.

```
    var dd = new DocData{id = "hi", Name = "world"};
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new[]{dd, dd}, new JsonSerializerSettings{PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects}).Dump();
// Output: [{"$id":"1","$id":"hi","Name":"world"},{"$ref":"1"}]
```

Still, it seems like it should let you capture the `$id` property if you're not using reference handling.

As a workaround, you can parse it into a JObject, and pull the property out directly:

```
    var id = JObject.Parse(s)["$id"];
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocData>(s);
    obj.id = id;
```

Comment: Ha, just my luck. I guess (hope) having a $ as a leading character is a very rare occurrence. Maybe I can also get the service developer to change that, or explain why they want it like that.

Thanks

Comment: @user3063281: It turns out, it's even more specific than that. JSON.NET apparently uses `$id` as a reserved name to help it deal with object references. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542144/how-to-remove-id-during-json-serialization