# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject not working on 1 specific object ("$id") returns null is empty

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

This are my models:

```
 public class Object
 {
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "test1")]
     public string Test1 { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "test2")]
     public string Test2 { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_id")]
     public ID Id { get; set; }
 }

 public class ID
 {
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$id")]
     public string Id { get; set; }
 }
```

When I debug it show every value correctly, but after the JsonConvert. Id is empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Json body:

```
 "test1: "sometext",
 "test2": "sometext",
  "_id": {
    "$id": "thisisanidstring"
  }
```

Comment: Until you show us the JSON you're using to deserialize and the code you use to do so, answers will be guesses.

Comment: @spender yes I forgot that, updated.

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/issues/553 it says how to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

[This question is already there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361812/deserialize-json-in-c-sharp-with-illegal-variable-characters) Have a look.

Json.NET uses $id as a reserved word to help it deal with object references.